# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`robot`.`specifications`, CONSTRAINT `specifications_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Product_code`) REFERENCES `product shipment` (`Product_code`))

Im new to this, and i really dont know what im getting out here!? :oo

I'm almost 100% sure that i defined my primary and foreign keys correctly in my other tables..

Can anyone tell me in native english, what im doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please show us the tables and the query you ran?

Comment: i would very much, i made an ER diagram, but i am not allowed to upload anything without reputation :(

Comment: ____________
Product Code

Comment: without table or query how other people will solve your problem

Comment: Product shipment 
____________
Amount *  Product_code  *  Shipment_ID 
2      *      12345     *     1111
3      *      23456     *     2222
4      *      34567     *     3333
5      *      45678     *     4444
6      *      56789     *     5555

Shipment

________
Shipment_ID  *  Origin  *  Arrival_Date  *  Placement
1111         * Fredericia* 2014-01-01    *     1
2222         *  Vejle   *  2014-01-02    *     2
3333         *  Kolding *  2014-01-03    *     3
4444         * Aarhus   *  2014-01-04    *     4
5555         * Odensen  *  2014-01-05    *     5

Specifications 
__ 
Product_code

Comment: oh shit.. this looked more useable when i was writing it :o

Comment: You can edit your post above and add it in a [code] tag

Answer (score 0):

References to non-existent values in the tables can cause this problem. I have faced it more than once when setting up a foreign key constraint in tables with data in it.

The solution to this problem is finding the references to non-existent rows and deleting them. Once this is done, if the syntax and table definitions are correct, the constraints should function.

```
Table : Country
cid  |    Name    |   Comment
---------------------------------
1    |    Japan   |   xyz
2    |    USA     |   pqr
3    |    India   |   abc
4    |    Germany |   lmn
30   |    France  |   pqr

Table : Language
lid  |  country_id | lang_name
---------------------------------
101  |      1      | Japanese
901  |      2      | Engligh
291  |      3      | Hindi
678  |      4      | German
283  |      30     | French
827  |      9      | Russian
```

As we can see that Language reff # 827 is refering to country reff # 9, but our country table does not have this value . There is no [9 | Russia | ghk ] there.

An attempt to create a foreign key constraint will fail with the following error

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_db`.`#sql-4ae_1f19e`, CONSTRAINT `country_ID_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`cid`))
```

Solution : We need to find all non-existent references and manually delete them. This is simple with small table. With tables with large data in it use the following query to find all non-existent references :

```
select country_id,(select count(*) from country where country_id = cid) from language WHERE country_id*(select count(*) from country where country_id = cid) = 0 ;
```

This will list all non-existent references. Once you have deleted the references, the constraint can be created with command :

```
ALTER TABLE language ADD CONSTRAINT country_if_fk FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country(`cid`);
```